# Ruby on Rails 4 Validation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm relatively new to Ruby on rails, and I'm trying to validate a field. I have an `Ask` model which belongs to a `User` model. The `User` has a parameter `account_dollars` and the `Ask` has a parameter `price`. When filling in the form to create an ask, I would like to validate that the `ask`'s `price` field is less than or equal to the current user's `account_dollars`.

### Ask.rb

```
class Ask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true,
  numericality: {greater_than: 0}
end
```

Thanks for the help with this basic question - I don't know enough yet to properly google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write custom validations in rails, I would do something like this:

```
 class Ask < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true,
    numericality: {greater_than: 0}
    validate :has_enough_dollars

    def has_enough_dollars
      if user.account_dollars < price
        errors.add_to_base("The price is larger than the user account balance")
      end
    end
  end
```

You can read more about rails validations here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had to use field validation as opposed to class/base level. ie: error.add(:price, "The price is larger than the user account balance") instead of error.add_to_base("...")